# Passive voice: The best answers are voted up and rise? to the top?

Tags: passive-voice

I think it should be: The best answers are voted up and risen to the top.

Since questions ARE... and ... (Past participle).

Answer (score 5):

First, let's take a look at the original sentence:

> The best answers **are voted up** and **rise to the top**.

This sentence is fine.  We can treat it as a reduced version of the following coordination of two clauses:

> The best answers **are voted up** and <s>the best answers</s> **rise to the top**.

It's true that one clause is passive and the other is active, but that's okay.  This sentence is grammatical.

You're probably trying to interpret it this way:

> *The best answers **are voted up** and <s>the best answers are</s> **rise to the top**.

Of course, if you interpreted it that way it would be ungrammatical because **are rise* is ungrammatical.  That's not the right interpretation, but it explains why you wanted to change it to *risen*.  You wanted them both to be passive because you interpreted the passive auxiliary *are* as applying to both clauses.

Unfortunately, your version is ungrammatical:

> *The best answers **are voted up** and **risen to the top**.

The full version would look like this:

> *The best answers **are voted up** and <s>the best answers are</s> **risen to the top**.

**Are risen*<sup>†</sup> is ungrammatical because *rise* is intransitive so it can't be cast in the passive.  When you turn an active clause into a passive clause, its object typically becomes the subject:

> *(active)* I voted up **the best answers**.　→
>   *(passive)* **The best answers** were voted up <s>by me</s>.

But that isn't possible when a verb is used intransitively because there is no object to move into subject position, so a passive cannot be formed.  That makes your version ungrammatical.

---

Notes:

<sup>†</sup> You may see the archaism *be risen* in religious texts, but it's no longer grammatical in Present Day English; rather than a passive, this is the (now archaic) *be*-perfect, meaning 'have risen'.  Still, because most English speakers are familiar with these religious texts, they might think of this when they hear the phrase *be risen*.

* In this answer, the * symbol marks a sentence or phrase as ungrammatical.

Comment: +1 OP might like to know that an acceptable way of casting the second verb in the passive would be "The best answers are voted up and **raised** to the top".